# Interacting with VideoJS cues (vtt captions) from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video.js

I'm attempting to interact with cues loaded from a `vtt` file via `video.js`. I can do it easily and repeatable from the browser inspect console but never from the `videojs` load-success function.  I have a suspicion that the `textTrack` is parsed (I can access id, kind, mode attributes) but not read (cues are null).  I can't find anywhere in the documentation or source if there is a way to force the track to be read or if there is a callback or event I should be listening for.

Thanks for any help!

Basic video.js invocation. Working fine, showing captions and video:

```
<video id="video" ..... >
  <source ..... />
  <track kind="captions" src="captions.vtt" srclang="en" default />
</video>
```

js, attempting to access cues:

```
<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = '/static/js/video-js.swf';
  var player = videojs('video', {}, function(){
      var tracks = player.textTracks();
      var captions; // captions track

      // find all the tracks we care about
      for (var i=0; i<tracks.length; i++) {
        var isCaptions = tracks[i].kind === "captions"
        if (isCaptions) {
          captions = tracks[i];
        }
      }
      console.log(captions, captions.id, captions.kind, captions.mode, captions.cues);
      player.play();
    }
  );
</script>
```

console.log:

```
t.t {d: t.Ea.extend.d, X: Array[0], Ga: Array[0], addEventListener: function, vdata1427596024498: 320…}
"vjs_text_track_316" "captions" "hidden" null
```

interactive console:

```
> c = player.textTracks()[0].cues[0].text
<- "first caption"
```

Tested with latest grunt-built master branch (version `4.12.5`) in Google Chrome Version `41.0.2272.104 (64-bit)`

Comment: Check out this issue on the video.js repo. I think it's related. https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/1949